# how to import bigquery module from google.cloud

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I am very new to SQL and I was instructed to run the code below:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
```

But I cant seem to go beyond the first step - i keep getting this error

---

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1035661e8528> in <module>
----> 1 from google.cloud import bigquery

ImportError: cannot import name 'bigquery' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)
```

Do any of you know a way around this?

Thank you

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.1

Comment: Have you installed google-cloud-bigquery dependencies. This should help https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-bigquery/

Answer (score 1):

You can install the BigQuery library using pip command.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#installing_the_client_library

Answer (score 1):

You first need to install `google-cloud-bigquery`.

`pip install --upgrade google-cloud-bigquery`